# Is this a bad approach to add conditional comments to wp_head?

Tags: conditional-tags, wp-head

Why people say this is a bad approach to add conditional comments to wp_head? For example:

```
function add_ie_html5_shim () {
    echo '<!--[if lt IE 9]>';
    echo '<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>';
    echo '<![endif]-->';
}

if ($GLOBALS['is_IE']) {
    add_action('wp_head', 'add_ie_html5_shim');
}
```

especially using the `$GLOBALS[]` inside if condition and outside a function.. Is it a BAD approach.. If yes WHY???

Comment: Why not just add the code using `add_action()` without the `$GLOBALS[]` conditional? You're effectively adding a double conditional here as the original strings you echo to the head are already conditional (i.e. `'<!--[if lt IE 9]>'`)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about how $['globals'] decides what browser you are using, i assume it uses some kind of browser sniffing which is generally a bad technique as the results it produces can be less than reliable.

Why do you need to use PHP anyway, just putting this as HTML in the head will achieve exactly the same effect.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: hard coding scripts is a bad approach according to wordpress, more over I have to provide users the ability to add either html5shim or modernizer and also I need to have a priority order for filters.. so hard coding is out of my options.. Any way Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a function [$is_IE](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables#Browser_Detection_Booleans) which will do what you need e.g.

```
function add_ie_html5_shim () {
 wp_register_script('html5_shim', 'http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js', array(), false);
 wp_enqueue_script('html5_shim');
}
if ( true === $is_IE ) {
 add_action('wp_head', 'add_ie_html5_shim');
}
```

Comment: It is not a function, it is a global variable and if statements alone are used for conditional checks you don't need `if(true === $is_IE)` just `if($is_IE)` is sufficient. My question is > Is it a bad idea to use `$GLOBALS[]` to get the global variables inside a conditional statement and out side a function..

Comment: I think this question suites php forum, anyway I don't have permission to move this post..